# Displaying multiple colors on a single data bar

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, colors, ssrs-2008

Okay I am going to try and be as clear as possible with my end goal here so I apologize if it does sound messy. I am trying to display a data bar that has a target of 10 for example. This data bar is displayed in grey. What I'd like to do is on the same data bar have the color green fill up as each target is completed. Here is a rough image of what I would like:

[image: Example]

I'm trying to do this in ssrs within a matrix. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it or if anyone needs more detail please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is built to provide a knowledge base for other developers with similar problems. For posterity, please rephrase your question so that it has a clear question, including technologies used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your column group and insert 'inside group'.
Drag and drop a Data Bar into your new cell.
Choose a stacked bar.
Click on the new chart, so that Chart Data appears.
Add your first value, the one you wish to be, for example, green.
Add a second value, adding the same value as before.
Change the expression on this second value to be 10 - 'Value'